# Getting Selected Drop-Menu Value to Pass into Second Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code to generate a drop-menu whose contents come from an array. That part is working. However, I need to then pass the value selected from the drop-menu into my `populateJobVal()` function when a user clicks on one of the menu elements - so that that value will get printed to the input field. Right now when I run this code, what gets printed to the input field is `[object HTMLUListElement]`.

I assume all I need to do here is pass the correct value to my `populateJobVal()`, however, so far it hasn't worked as expected. I've tried adjusting the code as follows:

`a.setAttribute('onclick', 'populateJobVal(opt)');`

... However, nothing at all prints to the input field in this case. What do I need to pass here? Or am I missing something?

```
  <script>
    let select = document.getElementById("selectJob");
    let options = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3", "Job 4", "Job 5"];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      let opt = options[i];
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.textContent = opt;
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.setAttribute('onclick', 'populateJobVal(selectJob)'); // What to pass here?
      a.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-link');
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(a);
      select.appendChild(li);
    }

    function populateJobVal(val) {
      document.getElementById("selection").value = val;
    }

  </script>
```

My relevant HTML code looks like this:

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Select Job Type to Schedule
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selectJob">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way you're adding the click event, much easier to pass the `opt` argument. The previous way you were passing the entire list.

Replace

```
a.setAttribute('onclick', 'populateJobVal(opt)');
```

With

```
 a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    populateJobVal(opt)
 }); // Look here
```

```js
let select = document.getElementById("selectJob");
let options = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3", "Job 4", "Job 5"];
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  let opt = options[i];
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.textContent = opt;
  a.setAttribute('href', '#');
  a.addEventListener('click', () => {
    populateJobVal(opt)
  }); // Look here
  a.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-link');
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(a);
  select.appendChild(li);
}

function populateJobVal(val) {
  debugger
  document.getElementById("selectJob").value = val;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Select Job Type to Schedule
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selectJob">
  </ul>
</div>
```